# Swift framework for iOS and macOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos, frameworks

currently i'm developing an app for my graduation project. The problem is, that it's not just one app, it consists of an iOS app that is made for the users and a macOS app for the "Owner". In the mac App the owner can create a file that should then be red in the iOS app.

Until now I have made a script that has all the necessary variables to transport the information, it can serialise and deserialise a file and assign it to the UI. Everything worked fine as long as I was working on the macOS app, the files can be created, deserialised and so on, however when I tried to go to the iOS app, I copied the exact same script that serves as the dataModel into the project and when I tried to deserialise a file created in the macOS file the app crashed and gave me an error saying:

> cannot decode object of class (ExcursionCreator.ExcursionDataModel)
>   for key (root); the class may be defined in source code or a library
>   that is not linked'

I investigated on the error and found out that i cannot just copy the script from one project to the other, so I found a source that said that I should create a framework with just this file, however i haven't found any useful topics that talk about frameworks for cross platform.

So my question in a few words is, is it true that I have to create a framework for this purpose and if so how would I do it so it works on macOS as well on iOS. Any other advice would also be greatly appreciated.   Thanks in advance Jorge. :)

### Update

As asked by danielv here is my code where I store the information, it also conforms to the NSCoding protocol so i can serialise and deserialise it:

```
import Foundation

class ExcursionDataModel: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var title: String

    var imagesData = [Data]()
    var thumbnailImageData: Data?
    var shortText = String()
    var completeText = String()

    var difficulty: String = "Hard"
    var duration: String = "Long"

    var isFavourite: Bool = false
    var type: excursionType = .other

    enum excursionType: String {
        case biking
        case rafting
        case other
    }

    static let possibleDifficulties = ["Hard", "Medium", "Easy"]
    static let possibleDurations = ["Long", "Medium", "Short"]

    init (title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }

    override init() {
        self.title = "Title"
    }

    struct PropertyKey {
        static let titleKey = "title"
        static let imagesKey = "images"
        static let thumbnailImageKey = "thumbnailImage"
        static let shortTextKey = "shortText"
        static let completeTextKey = "completeText"
        static let difficultyKey = "difficulty"
        static let durationKey = "duration"
        static let isFavouriteKey = "isFavourite"
        static let typeKey = "type"
    }

    //MARK: - NSCoding

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

        aCoder.encode(title, forKey: PropertyKey.titleKey)
        aCoder.encode(imagesData, forKey: PropertyKey.imagesKey)
        aCoder.encode(thumbnailImageData, forKey: PropertyKey.thumbnailImageKey)
        aCoder.encode(shortText, forKey: PropertyKey.shortTextKey)
        aCoder.encode(completeText, forKey: PropertyKey.completeTextKey)
        aCoder.encode(difficulty, forKey: PropertyKey.difficultyKey)
        aCoder.encode(duration, forKey: PropertyKey.durationKey)
        aCoder.encode(isFavourite, forKey: PropertyKey.isFavouriteKey)
        aCoder.encode(type.rawValue, forKey: PropertyKey.typeKey)
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let title = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.titleKey) as! String

        self.init(title: title)

        self.imagesData = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.imagesKey) as! [Data]
        self.thumbnailImageData = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.thumbnailImageKey) as? Data
        self.shortText = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.shortTextKey) as! String
        self.completeText = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.completeTextKey) as! String
        self.difficulty = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.difficultyKey) as! String
        self.duration = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.durationKey) as! String
        self.isFavourite = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.isFavouriteKey) as! Bool
        self.type = excursionType(rawValue: aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.typeKey) as! String)!
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try using Firebase to keep all your information in sync!

Comment: I suggest you update your question with some code that explains what exactly you are trying to do, how do you serialize/deserialize objects and what is this "script" that you mention being moved from project to project. Framework is just a way to package code into reusable library with additional information, I don't think frameworks has any direct connection to your question (aside from being one possible way to refactor your code to better suit multi platform development).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [NSCoder documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscoder):

> NSCoder operates on objects, scalars, C arrays, structures, and
>   strings, and on pointers to these types. It does not handle types
>   whose implementation varies across platforms, such as union, void *,
>   function pointers, and long chains of pointers. A coder object stores
>   object type information along with the data, so an object decoded from
>   a stream of bytes is normally of the same class as the object that was
>   originally encoded into the stream.

The class that you encoded in your MacOS app is `ExcursionCreator.ExcursionDataModel`. Your iOS app, however, probably has different module name, so even if you include the exact same swift class in your iOS app, the actual namespaced class name would be different, e.g `ExcursionIOSApp.ExcursionDataModel`.

NSCoder has no idea these are the same classes, when it tries to decode the ExcursionDataModel it doesn't find it, so you get the error.

Your options are:

**Option #1**

Use an open portable format for your serializations. JSON is a popular choice but there are others. This has a benefit of reusability in platforms outside of Apple's ecosystem, if you later decide to port your app to, say, Android.

There is a foundation JSON serialization support in MacOS/iOS and many open source projects that offer better/additional JSON support.

**Option #2**

Use a different class that shares same implementation and name across platform. For example, you could use NSDictionary as your data structure. Just be sure that everything you put there is compliant with the restrictions required by NSCoder

**Option #3**

Put your data class in a framework. This will force the class to have the same name when used from both projects.

To create a framework, choose a MacOS framework project when creating a new projects. Add your `ExcursionDataModel` to this framework.

Note that you will need to compile this framework for each platform separately. So once you have it for MacOS you will need to add additional target for it in xcode to compile it for iOS.

Then include your framework's project in each of you apps. Make sure to remove the class from your app's sources.

Check Apple's [Framework Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html),

Personally, I'd go with **option #1** and use open and popular format and stay away from Apple's proprietary serialization.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I was thinking that creating a framework wasn't the smartest idea. I hadn't thought about the portable format, so i'll try that out. Thanks again for taking your time :)

Comment: Frameworks are an essential part of MacOS/iOS development and have many uses. If you go with the NSCoder approach, framework is the right solution. 


Also, generally on Stack Overflow if you find an answer useful, you may consider up voting it and possibly marking it as acceptable answer. This rewards the person who answered you with reputation and may encourage people to provide more answers to your and others questions in the future.